# Has universality been definitely established for the whole Selberg class?

Tags: l-functions, selberg-class

I juste googled to get some insight about universality for l-functions belonging to the Selberg class, but it seems that the proof requires the validity of the prime number theorem for the considered l-functions. Still, Yoshikatsu Yashiro uploaded a preprint on Arxiv pretending to give an unconditional proof of this prime number theorem for the whole Selberg class. So, has universality for all l-functions in the Selberg class been definitely established?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add references.

Comment: The first article can be found there:http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10986-010-9087-z

Comment: And the second one there:http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.0754

Comment: Did you ask the author via email?

Comment: No. By the way, which author do you talk about? Yoshikatsu Yashiro?

Comment: authors... I d send a joint email at all of them in this case.

Comment: I just emailed Yashiro-sensei. The response might not come before a few days though, since the golden week is probably about to start in Japan.

Comment: Joern Steuding sent me his article, and the condition in it to prove the universality is the assumption that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{\pi(x)}\sum_{p\leqslant x}\vert a_{p}\vert^{2}=k$ with $k$ a constant. The PNT for the Selberg class is $\sum_{n\leqslant x}b_{n}\log n\sim mx$ with $m$ the order of the pole of $F$ at $s=1$. It remains to show that the latter implies the former.

Comment: Is there any news about this issue?